# Getting error source/class not found

Tags: android

I am using service in my program where i have MainActivity.java and MyService.java in Mainactivity i called intent as

```
public void onClick(View src)
    {
        switch (src.getId()) {
        case R.id.ButtonStart:
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting service");
            startService(new Intent(this,com.example.MyService1.class));
            break;
        case R.id.ButtonStop:
            Log.d(TAG,"onClick: stopping service");
            stopService(new Intent(this,com.example.MyService1.class));
            break;

        }
    }
```

but i am getting error on Log.d that "WARN/ActivityManager(68): Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.example/.MyService1 }: not found" please tell me solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using file `MyService.java` and starting service like this:

```
startService(new Intent(this,com.example.MyService1.class));
```

Now insure that why you are using `com.example.MyService1.class` instead of `MyService` here?

Just simply use like this: `startService(new Intent(this,MyService.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you declared your service in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

`<service android:name="com.example.MyService1"/>`